# Python open a file with GUI

Tags: python

How can I open a file via Python through its actual application? Not open(filename), but to actually view the file myself on the computer. Can I do it with subprocess.run and use a terminal command? (I'm on windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do it in one of the following ways:

- [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)
- [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile)

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run('notepad.exe')
```

or

```py
import os
os.startfile('textfile.txt')
```

which will open the textfile with the program associated with txt files.